# Ошибка extends : как убрать extends?

Tags: java, ооп, наследование

```
class Calculator {
   int c;

   public void addition(int a, int b) {
      c = a + b;
      System.out.println("Сумма чисел: " + c);
   }

   public void subtraction(int a, int b) {
      c = a - b;
      System.out.println("Разность чисел: " + c);
   }
}

public class My_Calculator extends Calculator {
   public void multiplication(int a, int b) {
      c = a * b;
      System.out.println("Произведение чисел: " + c);
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      int a = 10, b = 20;
      My_Calculator cal = new My_Calculator();
      cal.addition(a, b);
      cal.subtraction(a, b);
      cal.multiplication(a, b);
   }
}
```

Comment: И в чём ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы убрать `extends`:

```
class Calculator {
  private int c;

  public void addition(int a, int b) {
    c = a + b;
    System.out.println("Сумма чисел: " + c);
  }

  public void subtraction(int a, int b) {
    c = a - b;
    System.out.println("Разность чисел: " + c);
  }
  public void multiplication(int a, int b) {
    c = a * b;
    System.out.println("Произведение чисел: " + c);
  }

}

public class My_Calculator  {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    Calculator cal = new Calculator();
    cal.addition(a, b);
    cal.subtraction(a, b);
    cal.multiplication(a, b);
  }
}
```